# How to create random extrusion distance for n x n square model?

Tags: modeling

I want to recreate the attached image as best I can. Is there a good/easy way to create randomness in how much each face is extruded? My goal is a square grid that is approximately 10 x 10, and then those random extrusions with a color gradient. I am relatively new to Blender so any help is very appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use a very simple Geometry Nodes setup for this.

Start with a grid with 11 vertices so that you have a 10x10 face grid. Next use a Split Edges node to seperate these faces. Scale down these faces by a small amount if you want seperated columns. Next, use a Extrude Mesh node to extrude these faces. Plug a random value node into the Offset Scale. Finally use a Set Material to assign a material to this geometry.

[image]

The material setup is one of the simplest ones. Just seperate out the Z component and use it as an input for an Emmision Shader. (Use the object coordinates instead of the generated ones if you don't want the gradient to always stay from 0-1.)
[image]

This should give you something that looks like this:
[image]

If you want the outlines too, there are a few different ways to go for it. The simplest one would be the inverse hull method. But there are a few different other options. There are a lot of existing resources for outlines, and therefore, I won't include that in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd> Add a new Plane.
2. <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd> Edit Mode
3. $\color{#888}{█0}\color{green}{█}$ *right mouse button*, <kbd>S</kbd> Subdivide
4. <kbd>F9</kbd> Specify the number of cuts.
5. <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, then <kbd>`I`</kbd> Extrude **Individual** Faces
6. <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`I`</kbd> Invert Selection
7. <kbd>H</kbd> Hide everything but the top faces
8. Enable proportional editing, **random** falloff.
9. <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> Move vertices up, don't confirm yet
10. $\color{#888}{█}\color{green}⬇\color{#888}{█}$ *mouse wheel down* until all verts have roughly the equal distribution.
11. Click to confirm movement, <kbd>O</kbd> disable proportional editing.
12. <kbd>A</kbd> Select all.
13. <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>`I`</kbd> Set Pivot to Individual Origins
14. <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> Flatten on $z$ axis.
15. <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> Reveal hidden

[image]